# When printing an HTML table of multiple pages, how to adjust column width just regarding to the table on current page only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print a large table with HTML.

[image]

See the screenshot: **the first column in the page 1 is unnecessarily wide, it can be narrower.** How can I tell the render not to care about elements on other pages?

**Test online**: https://jsfiddle.net/6n4medx3/1/ (It will open a print preview automatically for you.)

**Code**:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong line.</td>
            <td>Oops!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
// add enough rows, so that the page will break, to demostrate the scenario
for (let i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    let row = $('<tr>')
        .html($('<td>').html('Hello!'))
        .append($('<td>').html('World!'))
    
    $('table').prepend(row)
}

window.print()
</script>
```

Comment: I think maybe I am using the wrong tool, but I can't come up with better. I firstly tried MS EXCEL, which performs the same behaviour and there seems no configurations for this.

Comment: I have just come up with a workaround: split table by page manually with JavaScript. I will add rows one by one, get the table height, see if it is enough for a page, start at a new table. then break page. See if it works ...

Comment: Yeah, some workaround like that is what you’ll have to use. The inherent behavior of a table does not change all of a sudden, just because the table is printed over multiple pages.